# Variable explorer in Spyder: how to keep visualizing variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

**Context**:

I am running a script that creates many variables. After the execution of script, I am able to print everything I want (for viasualing purposes) using the IPython Console.

The variable explorer is filled with the variable only during the execution of the script. When the script ends, the variables are no longer visible. **Please note** that I am sure they are still there because I can do a simply print from the IPython Console.

**Question**:

How to keep the variables visible even after the end of the script?

**Temporary walkaround**:

I just insert a breakpoint in the last dummy instruction of the script that, in many cases, it is a useless ad-hoc-inserted `print("goodbye")`. In this case, the script is still running and, thus, the variables present in the variable explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

I had this problem until I used Spyder version 3.3. After an upgrade of the tool with:

```
conda update -n $ENV_NAME spyder
```

Spyder version 4.0 was installed. This was enough to solve the problem. The variables are there even after the execution of the script.

Here a screenshot of the variable explorer correctly filled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the list in a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv
import os


#create dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])

new_row = {'A':insertyourvariable}
#append row to the dataframe 
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel(r'results.xlsx')
```

Comment: this is a nice trick but it does not answer the question "How to keep the variables visible [in Spyder variable explorer] even after the end of the script?"